# Выбрать из таблицы лучшего по количеству продаж из филиала

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

Доброе время суток!

Есть две таблицы:

Таблица1. Общая

| idФилиала | Сотрудник | idТоварпроданого |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Иванов | 11 |
| 2 | Петров | 11 |
| 1 | Иванов | 23 |
| 2 | Сидоров | 43 |
| 2 | Сидоров | 15 |
| 2 | Сидоров | 15 |
| 1 | Орлов | 33 |

Таблица2. О Филиале

| idФилиала | Название Филиала |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Юг |
| 2 | Север |

Необходимо вывести ответ на запрос в котором будет отображаться лучший сотрудник продавший больше всего товара по филиалам.

| Название Филиала | Сотрудник |
| --- | --- |
| Юг | Иванов |
| Север | Сидоров |

Моих знаний хватило только на отображение лучших по продажам:

```
SELECT Таблица1.Сотрудник, COUNT(Таблица1.Сотрудник) as 'Всего', Таблица1.Название Филиала  
FROM Таблица1, Таблица2 WHERE Таблица1.idФилиала = Таблица2.idФилиала  
GROUP BY Таблица2.Название Филиала,Таблица1.Сотрудник 
ORDER BY Всего DESC
```

Подскажите как это возможно и куда копать.
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: [Копать в оконные функции](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html), которые позволяют задать номера строкам по группам и порядку (row_number() over..., rank() over ..., dense_rank() over ...). Они различные в деталях, но в простейшем случае `row_number over (partition by филиал order by count(сотрудник) desc) as rn` задаст им номера внутри группы филиала. Дальше только отобрать нужные `select * from (запрос) s where s.rn = 1`.

Comment: Спасибо за наводку. Попробую изучить оконные функции!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.id_branch,t1.emb,t1.sprod, t2.branch
FROM    (SELECT id_branch,emb,count(emb) as sprod
         FROM tab1 GROUP BY emb) as t1,
         tab2 as t2
WHERE t1.id_branch=t2.id
GROUP BY t1.id_branch
HAVING max(t1.sprod)
```

---

```
id_branch   emb        sprod    branch
1           Иванов        2      Юг
2           Сидоров       3      Север
```

---

```
tab1
    id  id_branch   emb prod
    4   2        Сидоров    43
    7   1        Орлов      33
    3   1        Иванов     23
    5   2        Сидоров    15
    6   2        Сидоров    15
    1   1        Иванов     11
    2   2        Петров     11
tab2
id  branch
1   Юг
2   Север
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Но видимо я плохо выразился столбец "idТоварапроданого" это не количество товара, а просто название проданного товара. Сама таблица она общая и в ней просто хранится информация о том какой товар кем и где был продан.
И суть вопроса как найти сотрудника продавшего больше всего товара в каждом филиале.

Comment: Правильно я понимаю, что количество одинаковых фамилий=количеству продаж, этого сотрудника? И нужно выбрать макс количество продаж по отделу. Т.е. подсчитываем количество продаж и выбираем макс количество, по отделам? Если да, то sum меняем на count? `SELECT id_branch,emb,sum(prod) as sprod` `SELECT id_branch,emb,count(emb) as sprod`

Comment: Да. Вы верно поняли. Попробую ваш вариант.